# how to write reusable code for login activity and login dialog box in android?

Tags: android, facebook-login, google-signin

I want to implement login activity but the user can skip that log in functionality in the first. After some time if user wants to log in or when user click buy button for buying product if user not logged in that time I want to display a login dialog box(remember I am not calling login activity).3 ways of login functionalities are there in my login activity (mail id(only),Facebook and Gmail).But in login dialog box only Facebook and Gmail logins are there.So these two logins I want a reusable code.Give me suggestions how can I do that?

Comment: I think this can be achieved using fragment so for activity use fragment activity and dialog fragment dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate activity for building the `AlertDialog` and call from which ever activity you need.
Implement the following `api` in that activity.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but in login activity user can login in 3 ways but in login dialog user can login only 2 ways.I am not calling that intent again.but i want reduce facebook and google api logins code.

Comment: make the alertDialog layout separate and login activity layout separate. so you can use layoutInflater in same activity. OnClick you can use particular api code